# Preventing Fullcalendar of adding a new click event handler for the same element when month is changed

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a click event handler in EventAfterAllRender callback and I don´t know the reason but every time I change the month in timelineMonth, a new click handler is added to the same element, triggering as many times as handlers have been added when I click the element.

How can I avoid this? I thought of placing click handler code outside fullCalendar but I need it fires in timelineMonth view. I need to limit one click handler per element.

```
$(function() { // document ready

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    editable: true,
    navLinks: true,
    header: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timelineDay,timelineMonth'
    },
    defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
    // This handler is added as many times as I change the month
    // and I need to prevent this
    eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {

        $("td.fc-resource-area tr").on('click', function(e) {
                alert ("Hi!")      
      });   
    },

    resourceGroupField: 'building',
    resourceColumns: [
        {
            labelText: 'first column',
            field: 'title',
            width: 150
        }
    ],
    resources: [{
      id: 'a',
      building: '460 Bryant',
      title: 'Click here',
      title2: 'Auditorium A\nAddition info'
    }, {
      id: 'b',
      building: '460 Bryant',
      title: 'Click here',
      eventColor: 'green'
    }, {
      id: 'c',
      building: '460 Bryant',
      title: 'Click here',
      eventColor: 'orange'
    }],
    events: [{
      id: '1',
      resourceId: 'b',
      start: '2016-12-07T02:00:00',
      end: '2016-12-07T07:00:00',
      title: 'event 1'
    }, {
      id: '2',
      resourceId: 'c',
      start: '2016-12-07T05:00:00',
      end: '2016-12-07T22:00:00',
      title: 'event 2'
    }, {
      id: '3',
      resourceId: 'f',
      start: '2016-12-07T00:30:00',
      end: '2016-12-07T02:30:00',
      title: 'event 5'
    }]
  });

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvos6f82/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new click handler is added because you can add an infinite number of event handlers to an element - adding a new one doesn't remove the old ones. And of course every time you change the date it re-renders the events, but it doesn't re-render the resources, so more handlers just get added to the existing resource elements.

You can solve it using [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove all previous event handlers on the selected elements i.e.

```
$("td.fc-resource-area tr").off().on('click', function(e) { alert ("Hi!") });
```

Update to your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xvos6f82/6/

Comment: This could solve my problem if it doesn´t prevent of clicking into another icons inside `td.fc-resource-area tr`. Do you know any way to apply `off()` and `on()` only to that element and not its children?

Comment: As per the jQuery docs I think you can do it using custom namespaces for the click event - does this: https://jsfiddle.net/xvos6f82/7/ do what you want?